# Return data between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some code which parses through a number of .CVS files, retrieves all the data for several columns and places the data in a data frame (called dfs).  I am now trying to return all of the data fields in dfs that are between two dates only.

I am trying to use the command:

```
return dfs[(dfs['date'] >= startDate) & (dfs['date'] <= endDate)]
```

but get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'date'
```

Could someone let me know what I've done wrong please? 
Please see below for my code:

```
def getTimeseriesData(path,column_num,startDate,endDate):
    colNames = ['date']
    dfs = []

    allfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
    for fname in allfiles:

        name = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
        name = os.path.split(name)[1]
        colNames.append(name)

        df = pd.read_csv(fname, header=None, usecols=[0, column_num,4,5], 
                        parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True,
                        index_col=[0], names=['date', name+'_LAST',name+'_VOLUME',name+'_MKTCAP'])

        df = df.groupby(level=0).agg('mean')

        dfs.append(df)        

    dfs = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

    return dfs[(dfs['date'] >= startDate) & (dfs['date'] <= endDate)] #<<--I think this is the problem
```

the head of dfs (from which I want to return data between two dates (say between 2001-01-03 and 2001-01-05) looks like this:

```
            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  \
date                                                                            
2001-01-02                  572               26605510               37494.60   
2001-01-03                  560               24715470               36708.00   
2001-01-04                  613               52781855               40182.15   
2001-01-05                  630               56600152               41296.50   
2001-01-08                  633               41014402               41493.15   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  
date                                                                           
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN  
2001-01-03               225.00              444328736            145216.0020  
2001-01-04               239.00              488568000            154251.6643  
2001-01-05               242.25              237936704            156349.2288  
2001-01-08               227.75              658059776            146990.8642
```

Comment: Can you give some example csv dada?

Comment: Hi linusg, sure, sample data now included in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `date` is the name of your index and not a column name:

Change:

```
return dfs[(dfs['date'] >= startDate) & (dfs['date'] <= endDate)]
```

into:

```
return dfs[(dfs.index >= startDate) & (dfs.index <= endDate)]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that hit the spot

Comment: Your code does not look like coming  from my answer. I use: `dfs[(dfs.index >= startDate) & (dfs.index <= endDate)] `.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it much simpler if your index is monotonically increasing sequence of dates:

showing all rows, but only first two columns:

```
In [98]: df.iloc[:, [0,1]]
Out[98]:
            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME
date
2001-01-02                  572               26605510
2001-01-03                  560               24715470
2001-01-04                  613               52781855
2001-01-05                  630               56600152
2001-01-08                  633               41014402
```

filtering rows, showing first two columns:

```
In [99]: df.loc['2001-01-03':'2001-01-05', df.columns[0,1]]
Out[99]:
            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME
date
2001-01-03                  560               24715470
2001-01-04                  613               52781855
2001-01-05                  630               56600152
```

or in your case:

```
return dfs.loc[startDate:endDate]
```

Comment: Slicing only works  same as the method of the OP if the dates are monotonic increasing.

Comment: @MikeMüller, that's not correct. Using `.ix[]` will also work on randomly distributed dates in the index

Comment: Try: `r = df.reindex(df.index[::-1])` Now `r[(r.index >= start) & (r.index<=end)]` vs. `r.ix[start:end]`

Comment: @MikeMüller, i've added an example for you to my answer - please check

Comment: `len(r.ix[startDate : endDate])` --> `0` vs. `len(r[(r.index >= startDate) & (r.index <= endDate)])` --> `11`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, '&' is is bitwise "and", `and` is logical "and".

Best to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here.

```
return [df for df in dfs if df['date'] >= startDate and df['date'] <= endDate]
```

The will go through the `dfs` list, check for each element the `if` conditions and return a new list with all the elements that met those conditions.

Comment: Thanks C14L, I tried the line you posted but I got the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers.  Any idea what I should do?

Comment: I don't know Pandas, but there seems to be a string instead of a `dict()` or `list()` somewhere. Does this `dfs = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)` convert the `dfs` list into a string? Or maybe `df = df.groupby(level=0).agg('mean')` converts the individual `df` lines into a string? To be able to sort it, you need a `list()` of `dict()` objects. If you have a table that is one long string, you would need to parse it before being able to sort it.